# Copying specific coloured cells onto a different worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a spreadsheet with conditional formatting, which turns some cells green and some red, depending on if they are in/out of the correct range.

What I need is for the red "out of spec" numbers to be copied onto the next sheet leaving the green "within spec" number off the second sheet. A bit like this:

Sheet 1:

a 2

b 4

c 5

d 6

e 3

Sheet 2:

a

b 4

c 5

d 6

e

I hope this makes sense, I did take screenshots but I can't post them! My fingers are crossed that someone can help :)

Thank you in advance
Jazz

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I have, I can get the data to move sheets, but I can't figure out how to get just the red cells to move

Answer (score 1):

I have assumed that data is in Column A of Sheet1.

**Tested**

```
Sub checkColornCopy()
```

Find the last row for automation

```
lastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

sheet2Counter = 1

For i = 1 To lastRow
```

Extracting the color of the Cell interior

```
ConditionalColor = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex
```

Color Index 3 denotes "Red"

```
If ConditionalColor = 3 Then
```

If the color is Red thenCopying the cell content of Sheet1 to Sheet2

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(sheet2Counter, 1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
```

Making the cell content of Sheet1 blank

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = " "
sheet2Counter = sheet2Counter + 1

End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, I've tried this one too, but am getting no joy at all. I click the button, and nothing happens. Thank you for taking the time though :) I appreciate it, also, the data is in column B in the test I'm doing, but in the real spreadsheet its from B50:S100 :/

Comment: Could you post the input and desired output, because the above code worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best way to do it but, it worked for me. 
Try:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim cell As String

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

For i = 1 To 10

    'Check if font is red
    If Range("A" & i).Font.Color = "fontcolor" Then

    cell = Range("A" & i).Value
    'Check for a number in the cell and remove the right most number
    While IsNumeric(Right(cell, 1))
        cell = Range("A" & i).Value
        cell = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 1)
        Sheets("sheet2").Range("A" & i).Value = cell
    Wend

    Else
    'If font is not red then display cell value on sheet2
    Sheets("sheet2").Range("A" & i).Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
    End If

Next

Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
```

**Edited**
In this case "A3" has red font.
To find the color of your red font use:

```
sub Text_Color()
Dim color As String
'"A3" has red text.
color = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A3").Font.color
MsgBox "My text color is= " & color
End Sub
```

Take the number found in the msgbox, in this example 393372. And replace "fontcolor" from the above code with 393372 .

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the help! I've set this all up, but when I click the button that the macro is assigned to, it copys all the cells to the next sheet, whereas I only need the red ones to move. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to find the color of your red text. I edited my post to help you find that information. Hope that helps.

Comment: That'll be where I went wrong, I had a red fill in the cell, ill change it so it's red text instead when I get back to work in the new year. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you just changed the background color then try changing `.Font.Color` to `Interior.Color`. That should look for cell interior color instead of the font color.

Comment: Sorry to bring this back up again, Just got back to work! I'm using this:

Sub ColournCopy2()
Dim i As Integer
Dim cell As String
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
For i = 1 To 15
    'Check if font is red
    If Range("B" & i).Font.color = "fontcolor" Then
    cell = Range("B" & i).Value
    While IsNumeric(Right(cell, 1))
        cell = Range("B" & i).Value
        cell = Left(cell, Len(cell) - 1)
        Sheets("sheet2").Range("B" & i).Value = cell
    Wend
    Else
      Sheets("sheet2").Range("B" & i).Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value
    End If
Next
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
End Sub

Comment: but its just copying over the full "B" column, not just the cells with the red fill